# $\deg F=n,\deg G=m$. Exists $A,B\in\mathbb{F}\left[X\right]$ with $\deg A \leq m-1, \deg B \leq n-1$ such that $AF+GB=1$

Tags: polynomials

Let $F,G\in\mathbb{F}\left[X\right]$ be polynomials such that $\deg F=n,\deg G=m$. And $\gcd(F,G) = 1$ Then exists $A,B\in\mathbb{F}\left[X\right]$ such that $\deg A\leq m-1,\deg B\leq n-1$ and $AF+GB=1$

I know that from Bézout's polynomial remainder theorem $A,B$ do exist, But I don't know how to show that there can be $A,B$ such that $\deg A\leq m-1,\deg B\leq n-1$. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have found polynomials $C, D$ such that
$$
C F + D G = 1.
$$
Divide $C$ by $G$, to obtain
$$
C = Q G + R,
$$
for some polynomials $Q, R$, with $R$ being either zero, or nonzero, of degree less than $m$. Then
$$
1 = C F + D G = (Q G + R) F + D G
=
R F + (D + Q F) G.
$$
Note first of all that if $R = 0$, then $G$ is a nonzero constant, so $m = 0$, and we can simply choose $A = 0$ and $B = G^{-1}$.

If $R \ne 0$, then the degree of $1 - R F$ is greater than $0$, and at most $(m-1) + n$. But then so is the degree of $(D + Q F) G$. Since $G$ has degree $m$, it follows that $D + Q F$ has degree at most $n - 1$.

Then you can choose $A = R$ and $B = D + Q F$.